# Queuing on iTunes

Tags: itunes, music, spotify, queue-management

Is there a way of queuing songs i want to listen to on itunes, like how i can on spotify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in the US so haven't really played around with Spotify, but you can queue up songs to play using [iTunes DJ](http://www.apple.com/itunes/inside-itunes/2010/03/itunes-dj-and-the-apple-remote-app.html) either remotely or through your iPod/iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a playlist, then add songs to that playlist, then play the playlist in order.